# Python copy file from script directory to current directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have some pre-made files that is kept in the same directory as the python script, I want to copy those into the target directory when I run the script.

I don't want to hardcode the path, especially if the script folder is moved to around. How do you get the script's directory path?

```
import shutil
import os

file_name = "example.txt"
source_file = '/'.join([this_should_be_script_directory, file_name])
current_dir = '/'.join([os.getcwd(), file_name])

shutil.copy(source_file, current_dir)
```

Comment: `os.path.abspath(__file__)`?

Comment: Aside: the line `current_dir = '/'.join([os.getcwd(), file_name])` is superfluous.

Comment: Oh thank you, I guess I didn't know what questions to search for. @jonrsharpe